# Installation of SDL2 on WSL: Why can't the Dbus_Context be found?

Tags: c#, sdl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sdl-2, wsl-2

I have an issue on my WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows.

I try to install SDL2 following the instruction on the website at the Linux/Unix section.

When I try to make inside the build/ folder. I get the following error message:

```
path/SDL_fcitx.c:50:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_DBusContext’
   50 |     SDL_DBusContext *dbus;
```

I tried to check inside the SDL_fcitx.c file and it does include "SDL_dbus.h".
Just so you know, I had an issue before like: "/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter:" where I could fix it using the following command on all of my file: `sed -i -e 's\r$//' <file>`.

Weirdly enough, I can use SDL on C and 'C++' project, but I cannot find the 'SDL2.dll' that is necessary for me for a C# project.
I wanted to know if I should fix the installation and how, or how can I find the 'SDL2.dll'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I could have fix the issue.
It was really easy, I downloaded the SDL2.dll file online then I put it inside the `C:/Windows/system32` and the `C:/Windows/SysWOW64`.
I don't think you have to put it inside both directories and I also don't know if there was not any other solution.